# Regex to pick up comma and period Python

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to create a regex which could match the following pattern:

```
5,000
2.5
25
```

This is the regex I have thus far:

```
re.compile('([\d,]+)')
```

How can I adjust for the `.`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest method would just be this:

```
re.compile('([\d,.]+)')
```

But this will allow inputs like `...`. This might be acceptable, since your original pattern allows `,,,`. However, if you want to allow only a single decimal point you can do this:

```
re.compile('([\d,]+.?\d*)')
```

Note that this won't allow inputs like `.5`—you'd need to use `0.5` instead.

Comment: what if I did `re.compile('([\d,]*.?\d*)')`?

Comment: @JamesHallen That would also allow an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

I think the perfect regex would be

```
re.compile(r'\d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,3}')
```

This way you match one or two digits followed by a comma or a full stop, and then one to three digits.

You don't need the parentheses if you are not going to use the contents of the match later. Omitting them speeds up the process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very big but powerful regex to capture anything that is a valid number:

```
import re
string = """
5,000
2.5
25
234,456,678.345
...
,,,
23,332.1
abc
45,2
0.5
"""
print re.findall("(?:\d+(?:,?\d{3})*)+\.?(?:\d+)?", string)
```

output:

```
# Note that it will not capture "45,2" because it is invalid
# It instead does "45" and "2", which are each valid
['5,000', '2.5', '25', '234,456,678.345', '23,332.1', '45', '2', '0.5']
```

Comment: mmmmh, 42,5 is valid in many regions of the world...